# Is there a way to extract data contained in the private tags of a .tiff image of a graph created by software?

Tags: python, tiff

To preface this, I just want to say I am not overly experienced, and I am not a developer of any sort. This is also my first post on Stack Overflow so if I do anything wrong please let me know.

I am a physical chemist performing measurements using a Park Systems NX10 and it ouputs the data as a .tiff image. The measurement is just recording current, potential and time. What I want is the pure XY data of the current and potential so I can plot the graph myself.

The usual way to get this is to open the .tiff file in their proprietary software (XEI), right click the graph that comes up and export the data as a .txt file, which is what I want. The issue is I have to do a lot of these measurements so I would like to have a way to automate this data extraction.

My attempt is shown below. According to the manual for the machine I am using the data I need is enclosed in the private tags of the image, but this is all the information it gives. Using tifffile I extracted all the tags (of which there are 17 total) and the code below writes 2 files, with tag name 50438 and 50439. The only argument of `.decode()` that didn't give an error for every file was windows-1252. When I write the file, it gives some words that I expect (Sample Bias, Current etc) as well as a bunch of NULL characters when viewed in a text editor. I have tried changing the encoding of the text editor also to no avail.

```
import tifffile

filepath = r"filepath\scan.tiff"
i=0
with tifffile.TiffFile(filepath) as tif:
    for page in tif.pages:
        for tag in page.tags:
            tag_name, tag_value = tag.name, tag.value
            print('tag_name=',tag_name,'tag_value=',tag_value)

            try:
                
                new_string = tag_value.decode('windows-1252')
                newfile = open('newfile{}.txt'.format(i),'w')
                newfile.write(new_string)
                i+=1
                print('wrote file')
                newfile.close()
           
            except:
                print('wrong encoding')
```

My main question is, is it possible to do what I am attempting or is this proprietary software the only thing capable of it? If it is possible, does anyone have any idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like the private tags values are not ascii. You have to reverse engineer the format to extract the data. Could you post the output of `python -m tifffile --detail=3 --noplot=0 file.tif` or post a sample file?

Comment: Here is a sample file: http://www.filedropper.com/scan3210715025. Running that code on a file gives this: https://pastebin.com/1KDE8B0s