# python TiffFileError: invalid tag value offset

Tags: python, image, tiff

when I try to open the metadata of a .tif file (https://drive.google.com/file/d/10ZTLRazYbgm4pYEc3M7J7bP6590ZjNtY/view?usp=sharing) with `tifffile.TiffFile`, I get the following error message:

```
TiffPage 0: TiffFileError: invalid tag value offset
```

Also when I use `skimage.io.imread` to open the image itself (which works), I get the following warning:

```
UserWarning: corrupt value offset for tag 34682
  warnings.warn(str(e))
```

Anyone knowing what is going on?
Thank you!

Comment: Interesting - its not necessarily a python issue - it really does contain an unknown tag (as running `identify` from ImageMagick on it reports the same tag issue. Also can't find that tag in https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/search.html?q=34682&Submit=Find+Tags

Comment: Partly, its definitely helpful for understanding, as is this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68406570/is-there-a-way-to-extract-data-contained-in-the-private-tags-of-a-tiff-image-of. However I am still searching for a convenient way do pass the metadata into a python dictionary...

Comment: I saw that you posted some pytiff example before, did that work, I was not fast enough to try it on my own...

Comment: Finally solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69569953/convert-private-tiff-tag-into-python-dict